# android change shape color used in custom radio button programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, custom-controls, shapes

I create custom radio button use this code:

**layout.xml**

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/control_radio_button"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="false" />
```

**@drawable/control_radio_button**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/control_radio_bg_false" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/control_radio_bg_true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/control_radio_bg_true" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/control_radio_bg_false" />
</selector>
```

**@drawable/control_radio_bg_true**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="999dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#E0E0E0" />
    <solid android:color="#f44336" />
</shape>
```

**@drawable/control_radio_bg_true**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="999dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="6dp"
        android:color="#bfbfbf" />
    <solid android:color="#f44336" />
</shape>
```

can i change background of `@drawable/control_radio_bg_false` and `@drawable/control_radio_bg_true` programmatically.

I want create list of my custom radio button with different color with an adapter(in recyclerview).

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
(radio0.background as? ShapeDrawable)?.apply {
    paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.new_color)
}
```

You would need to handle states by yourself, but this should cover you.

Comment: i change background of drawable with this code: `val sd: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.control_radio_bg_false)` , `val gd: GradientDrawable = sd as GradientDrawable` , `gd.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.building_choose_image_option_blue))` as well for `R.drawbale.control_radio_bg_true` but after that code unable to use in adapter because every radio button added has blue color. 
I think that we must make all `ShapeDrawbale` programmatically then set as background in target control

Answer (score -1):

I did a lot of research for kotlin code and found this. Adding this here so that if someone else comes looking specifically for kotlin.
After adding your drawable shape as your view's background add the following code in respective activity.

```
YourViewID.background.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00000"),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)
```